# "Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI." when trying to run react native project

Tags: react-native, expo, homebrew

Once I hit
`expo start`
expo runs for a few seconds but then gives me the following error:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:178:28)
```

I already made some research and people say I should `brew install wingman`.
The problem is, when I try to do that I get:

```
Updating Homebrew...
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Casks
Updated 1 cask.

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "wingman".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Do you guys have any idea how I could get it running?

Best regards

Answer (score 20):

I think you may have misread wingman. Try instead reinstalling watchman:

`$ brew reinstall watchman`

Credit where credit is due: [here's a link to the forum I found this in](https://forums.expo.io/t/error-emfile-too-many-open-files/35564)

Answer (score 0):

Update your Expo CLI.

```
npm i expo-cli -g
```

Comment: Please drop the **ALL CAPS** from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue
And in my case, I just had to install Brew and Watcher