# Why do I keep getting this error code when starting Expo client

Tags: npm, expo

To run the app, choose one of:
› Scan the QR code above with the Expo app (Android) or the Camera app (iOS).
› Press a for Android emulator, or i for iOS simulator, or w to run on web.
› Press e to send a link to your phone with email.

Press ? to show a list of all available commands.
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:178:28)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: Is it true, that your system is macOS Big Sur 11.1? We're facing the same problem there. On macOS Catalina 10.15.7 everything is fine.

Comment: In this GitHub issue https://github.com/taskrabbit/ReactNativeSampleApp/issues/48 they propose to install watchman: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html

Comment: Me again: I can confirm that installing watchman (see comment above) did the trick for macOS Big Sur 11.1. Expo client is running. But I really don't know if this is your issue. As said: Please add some more information to your problem, so we can help you.

Comment: For me, this issue happened as a result of bumping up either NPM to 7.6.2 or NODE to 14.16.10 (from ~v12).

Comment: Similar if not duplicate threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752638/expo-developer-tools-is-disconnected-from-expo-cli-when-trying-to-run-react-n    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65172632/react-native-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code

Answer (score 9):

```
brew install watchman
```

running this command solved my exactly same problem. if you look at the error message you are getting, it says:

> Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch at
> FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange.

react native is able to use watchman internally to watch its files. I hope this will work for your as well

Answer (score 4):

Oybek's solution did not work for me, but it would work if had Intel based Mac computer.

For those who have **Apple M1 Silicon based machine** such command may be daysaver:

```
arch -arm64 brew install watchman
```

or

```
arch -arm64 brew reinstall watchman
```

when you have some bad installation of watchman already done.

Comment: Day saver really..! Helped me.! Thanks

Comment: I face "exit status 7" error, and this answer solve  my problem 